# JSP Error -- Equal Symbol Expected

Tags: java, jsp

I'm relatively new to JSPs, and I'm trying to use a FormBean within one of my files.
When I try to open the JSP page on a local Tomcat server, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /entryForm.jsp (line: 4, column: 21) equal symbol expected
```

The first five lines of my code are:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <%@ page import = "jared.simpledatabase.* %>

    <jsp:useBean id="form" class="jared.simpledatabase.FormBean" scope="session"/>
    <jsp:setProperty name="form" property="*"/>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's a guess - missing double quote:

```
<%@ page import = "jared.simpledatabase.*" %>
```

Comment: I'd prefer that you accept the answer and vote it up to your thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it made me wait an hour before I could accept the answer.

Comment: @duffymo I googled this error out of boundless laziness and your answer was spot on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a missing " in the jsp:param tag e.g.

```
<jsp:param name="X" value="{$someValue}/>
```

Changing it to ... fixed the issue

```
<jsp:param name="X" value="{$someValue}"/>
```